# Apply a branch to a past commit

Tags: git

In a project, I have a `dev` branch that is up to date with `master`.

I would like to bring the `dev` branch changes to a branch `past-master`, that is basically a version of `master` stopped at a previous commit.

I tried `git rebase dev` on `past-master` but that replay all the commits between the `past-master` and `master` before applying the branch.
`git cherry-pick A^..B` with A being the first `dev` commit and B the last one on `past-master`, fails conflicting for some reason.

Going in the `dev` branch and running `git format-patch past-master` generate all the commits patchs, and applying the ones from the `dev` branch one by one on `past-master` works, but feel very suboptimal.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the manpage for rebase should clear this all up for you.
There are three commits in play: HEAD, upstream, and onto.

The commits it applies are upstream..HEAD. It applies them *to* the *onto* branch.  Without --onto, onto is set to upstream. But you want this:

HEAD: dev

upstream: master

onto: past-master

```
git rebase --onto past-master master dev
```

The manpage has this exact example in it. The only difference is that all the commits of past-master are reachable from master, whereas in the example, next has some commits that are not reachable. But this is no impediment:

```
 Here is how you would transplant a topic branch based on one branch to another, to pretend that you forked the topic branch from the latter branch, using rebase --onto.

   First let’s assume your topic is based on branch next. For example, a feature developed in topic depends on some functionality which is found in next.

           o---o---o---o---o  master
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   o---o---o  topic

   We want to make topic forked from branch master; for example, because the functionality on which topic depends was merged into the more stable master branch. We want our tree to look like this:

           o---o---o---o---o  master
               |            \
               |             o'--o'--o'  topic
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next

   We can get this using the following command:

       git rebase --onto master next topic
```